# React Hook Form integrate MUI TextField with mask - Input loses focus when 1 character is typed in

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, react-tsx, react-imask

I create MUI TextField component and integration with 3rd party input mask libraries. Then I integrate my component with React Hook Form. Everything works as expected except that once I type any 1 character into the input, the input loses focus.

Here is the TextField component

```
import { TextFieldStyled } from "./styled";
import { CustomProps, InputTextProps } from "./type";
import React from "react";
import { IMaskInput } from "react-imask";

export const AppInputText = (props: InputTextProps) => {
    const {
        value,
        patternOnPress,
        onChange,
        maxLength,
        mask,
        ...restProps
    } = props;

    const TextMaskCustom = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, CustomProps>(
        function TextMaskCustom(props, ref) {
            const { onChange, ...other } = props;

            return (
                <IMaskInput
                    {...other}
                    mask={mask}
                    definitions={{
                        '#': /[6,8,9]/,
                    }}
                    inputRef={ref}

                    onAccept={(value: any) => onChange({ target: { name: props.name, value } })}
                    overwrite
                />
            );
        },
    );

    const handleKeyDown = (event: any) => {
        if (patternOnPress) {
            if (!patternOnPress.test(event.key)
                && event.key !== "Backspace"
                && event.key !== "ArrowLeft"
                && event.key !== "ArrowRight"
            ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <TextFieldStyled
            {...restProps}
            inputProps={{
                maxLength: maxLength,
            }}
            InputProps={{
                inputComponent: mask ? TextMaskCustom as any : undefined,
            }}
            value={value}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
    );
}
```

Here is the React Hook Form

```
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { FormInputTextProps } from "./type";
import { FormContainer, LabelContainer, LabelStyled } from "../styled";
import { AppInputText } from "../../Input/InputText";
import React from "react";
import { AppInfoIcon } from "../../../custom/InfoIcon";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import colors from "../../../../constant/colors";

export const FormInputText = React.forwardRef((props: FormInputTextProps, ref) => {
    const {
        name,
        control,
        label,
        labelInfo,
        placeholder,
        direction = "vertical",
        autoComplete,
        required,
        onChange: onChangeCallBack,
        ...restProps
    } = props;

    return (
        <Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            render={({
                field: { onChange, value },
                fieldState: { error }
            }) => (
                <FormContainer direction={direction}>
                    {label &&
                        <LabelContainer>
                            <LabelStyled>
                                {label}
                                {required &&
                                    <Typography color={colors.LINE_ERROR}>*</Typography>
                                }
                            </LabelStyled>
                            {labelInfo &&
                                <AppInfoIcon info={labelInfo} />
                            }
                        </LabelContainer>
                    }
                    <AppInputText
                        {...restProps}
                        helperText={error ? error?.message : null}
                        error={!!error}
                        fullWidth
                        onChange={(event: any) => {
                            onChange(event);
                            onChangeCallBack?.(event);
                        }}
                        value={value}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        autoComplete={autoComplete ? name : "off"}
                    />
                </FormContainer>
            )}
        />
    );
});
```

How do I resolve this issue?